# i try to run the application but it gives me these errors

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

lib/helper/notification_helper.dart:16:29: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'IOSInitializationSettings'.
var iOSInitialize = new IOSInitializationSettings();

lib/helper/notification_helper.dart:18:73: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onSelectNotification'.
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings, onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {

lib/view/screens/chat/chat_screen.dart:43:33: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'IOSInitializationSettings'.
var iOSInitialize = const IOSInitializationSettings();

here is my code in notification helper

```
class NotificationHelper {
....
  static Future<void> initialize(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    var androidInitialize = new AndroidInitializationSettings('notification_icon');
    var iOSInitialize = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationsSettings = new InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings, onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
      try{
        if(payload != null && payload.isNotEmpty) {
          MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState.push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrderDetailsScreen(orderModel: null, orderId: int.parse(payload))));
        }
      }catch (e) {}
      return;
    });
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("onMessage: ${message.notification.title}/${message.notification.body}/${message.notification.titleLocKey}");
  showNotification(message, flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin, false);
});
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print("onOpenApp: ${message.notification.title}/${message.notification.body}/${message.notification.titleLocKey}");
  try{
    if(message.notification.titleLocKey != null && message.notification.titleLocKey.isNotEmpty) {
      MyApp.navigatorKey.currentState.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrderDetailsScreen(orderModel: null, orderId: int.parse(message.notification.titleLocKey))));
    }
  }catch (e) {}
});


 static Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message, FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin fln, bool data) async {
String _title;
String _body;
String _orderID;
String _image;
if(data) {
  _title = message.data['title'];
  _body = message.data['body'];
  _orderID = message.data['order_id'];
  _image = (message.data['image'] != null && message.data['image'].isNotEmpty)
      ? message.data['image'].startsWith('http') ? message.data['image']
      : '${AppConstants.BASE_URL}/storage/app/public/notification/${message.data['image']}' : null;
}else {
  _title = message.notification.title;
  _body = message.notification.body;
  _orderID = message.notification.titleLocKey;
  if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    _image = (message.notification.android.imageUrl != null && message.notification.android.imageUrl.isNotEmpty)
        ? message.notification.android.imageUrl.startsWith('http') ? message.notification.android.imageUrl
        : '${AppConstants.BASE_URL}/storage/app/public/notification/${message.notification.android.imageUrl}' : null;
  }else if(Platform.isIOS) {
    _image = (message.notification.apple.imageUrl != null && message.notification.apple.imageUrl.isNotEmpty)
        ? message.notification.apple.imageUrl.startsWith('http') ? message.notification.apple.imageUrl
        : '${AppConstants.BASE_URL}/storage/app/public/notification/${message.notification.apple.imageUrl}' : null;
  }

  if(_image != null && _image.isNotEmpty) {
  try{
    await showBigPictureNotificationHiddenLargeIcon(_title, _body, _orderID, _image, fln);
  }catch(e) {
    await showBigTextNotification(_title, _body, _orderID, fln);
  }
}else {
  await showBigTextNotification(_title, _body, _orderID, fln);
}
```

and here is my code in chat screen :

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final OrderModel orderModel;
const ChatScreen({Key key,@required this.orderModel}) : super(key: key);
@override

 State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

final TextEditingController _inputMessageController = TextEditingController();
 FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
 bool _isLoggedIn;
bool _isFirst = true;

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
if(!kIsWeb){
var androidInitialize = const AndroidInitializationSettings('notification_icon');
  var iOSInitialize = const IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initializationsSettings = InitializationSettings(android: androidInitialize, iOS: iOSInitialize);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationsSettings);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    NotificationHelper.showNotification(message, flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin, false);

    Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context, listen: false).getMessages(context, 1, widget.orderModel, false);
  });
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context, listen: false).getMessages(context, 1, widget.orderModel, false);
  });
}
_isLoggedIn = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).isLoggedIn();
if(_isLoggedIn){
  if(_isFirst) {

    Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context, listen: false).getMessages(context, 1, widget.orderModel, true);
  }else {
    Provider.of<ChatProvider>(context, listen: false).getMessages(context, 1, widget.orderModel, false);
    _isFirst = false;
  }
  Provider.of<ProfileProvider>(context, listen: false).getUserInfo(context);
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code snippet like `chat/chat_screen.dart:`

Comment: I'll imagine flutter local notifications plugin isn't setup or done incorrectly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: okay i hope now someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

In `pubspec.yml` set **flutter_local_notifications: 9.1.4**

Answer (score 0):

In version 10+ IOSInitializationSettings and MacOSInitializationSettings were replaced by DarwinInitializationSettings
Check [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/CHANGELOG.md) for more details